# Using NGINX to access other systems with proxy_pass

Tags: proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get my NGINX reverse proxy to connect to 2 other systems using the the proxy_pass directive and I'm having  an issue with the configuration.

Here is the server block of my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /
    {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.50.8;
    }

    location /acp
    {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.50.9;
    }
}
```

So the "location " section works, but the "location \acp" section gives me a a 404 or 500 (it adds the "acp" to the URL which I don't really want it to do).

Id I swap the proxy_pass IPs, the "location " works the the new IP, and the "location \acp" doesn't.

I believe I want to remove the "acp" but I just can't seem to get it to do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The [`proxy_pass` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (when used within a prefix location) can be configured to remove the `/acp` prefix from the request, by adding a replacement URI to the end of the `proxy_pass` statement.

In your case, you would add a `/` to the end of the `proxy_pass` statement **and** add a trailing `/` to the `location` statement, so that the substitution works correctly.

For example:

```
location /acp/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://192.168.50.9/;
}
```

However, not all applications are well behaved. It is common to retrieve the HTML file correctly, but encounter problems retrieving the CSS/JS files.